# Why is log4j logging to two separate files?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have the following `log4j.properties` file, with a default appender and a separate one for a specific class

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT, default

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.default=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.default.File=my-log.log
log4j.appender.default.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.app.util.ReportUtil=DEBUG, report

log4j.appender.migrateReport=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.migrateReport.File=logs/report.log
log4j.appender.migrateReport.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.migrateReport.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

ReportUtil is set up to use this logger,

`private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportUtil.class);`

When I log from ReportUtil, it writes to both appenders - I only want it logging to `report`.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this `log4j.additivity.com.app.util.ReportUtil = false` to your configuration.

Comment: What does the additivity do?

Answer (score 0):

try removing default from your rootLogger. i believe when you have default specified in rootLogger, then it will always be invoked.